# git clone corrupting files which contains asian (UTF8) characters

Tags: git, utf-8

I have uploaded a repository from Mac to git server where repository was having html files with Asian characters, now when I am cloning the same repository in Windows7, the html files are showing corrupt data, while I can see on the gitweb that files on git server are good one. Any idea, what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Following is my git config

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
    autocrlf = false
    quotepath = off
[alias]
    st = status

[i18n]
    logoutputencoding = utf8
    commitencoding = utf8
```

Comment: My guess: nothing is corrupted, but your editor doesn't know that it should open the files as UTF-8. How did you verify that they are "broken"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Server-side" Git is not interested in the contents of your files -- it does not even know they exist as it operates on opaque blobs of data which clients send it.

Moreover "client-side" Git does not touch your files either unless [clean/smudge filters](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) are in place and/or EOL-conversion is enabled (which has nothing to do with encodings anyway so does not apply).

Hence I'm with @joahim-sauer on this matter — supposedly your problem is in *interpretation.* Note that Windows Notepad looks at [BOMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to know files are UTF-8, and you won't convince it a file is UTF-8 unless the file contains BOM, and many files doesn't (and many people think they shouldn't, ever).

Comment: Indeed @Joachim-Sauer was correct, it was the editor issue. Even though I was using Chrome to view those html's, it was showing those characters characters in absence of proper encoding in html.